# MVVM model - I can't find a bug that interferes with creating ViewModel

Tags: android, database, android-studio, kotlin, mvvm

I have a problem with View Model. In activity "Analysis" I had to break something in the code, and I can't find the error. Can somebody help me. I'm a newbie in the Android program and I often make stupid mistakes. I will try to find the error by then.
Thanks so much for your help
Regards

DAO
package com.example.mwproto1.ROOM

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.room.*

```
@Dao
interface PomiarDao {

    @Insert
    suspend fun addPomiar(pomiar: Pomiar)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM pomiar ORDER BY id DESC")
    suspend fun getAllPomiar():List<Pomiar>

    @Insert
    suspend fun addMultiplePomiar(vararg pomiar: Pomiar)

    @Update
    suspend fun  updatePomiar(pomiar: Pomiar)

    @Delete
    suspend fun deletePomiar(pomiar: Pomiar )

    @Query("SELECT avg(Stezenie) FROM Pomiar ")
     fun average(): LiveData<Float>
}
```

REPOSITORY

```
package com.example.mwproto1.ROOM

import android.app.Application
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Deferred
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.async

class Repository(application: Application) {


    private  var pomiardao: PomiarDao

    init {
        val database = Database
            .buildDatabase(application.applicationContext)
        pomiardao = database.getPomiarDao()

    }


    fun averageasync(): Deferred<LiveData<Float>> =
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).async {
            pomiardao.average()
        }

}
```

ViewModel

```
package com.example.mwproto1.ViewModel

import android.app.Application
import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import com.example.mwproto1.ROOM.Pomiar
import com.example.mwproto1.ROOM.Repository
import kotlinx.coroutines.Deferred
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking

class ViewModel(application: Application):AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private var PomiarRepository: Repository = Repository(application)

    private var allpomiar: Deferred<LiveData<Float>> =
        PomiarRepository.averageasync()


    fun AverageVM(): LiveData<Float> = runBlocking {
        allpomiar.await()
    }
}
```

Entity

```
package com.example.mwproto1.ROOM

import android.os.Parcel
import android.os.Parcelable
import androidx.room.ColumnInfo
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

    @Entity
    data class Pomiar(
        @ColumnInfo(name="Stezenie")
        val Stezenie: String?,
        @ColumnInfo(name="Data")
        val Data: String?,
        @ColumnInfo(name="Zegar")
        val Zegar: String?,
        @ColumnInfo(name="Posilek")
        val Posilek: String?,
        @ColumnInfo(name="Samopoczucie")
        val Samopoczucie: String?,
        @ColumnInfo(name="Stres")
        val Stres: String?,
        @ColumnInfo(name="Hiperglikemia")
        val Hiperglikemia: String?

    ): Parcelable{
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        var id :Int = 0

        constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
            parcel.readString(),
            parcel.readString(),
            parcel.readString(),
            parcel.readString(),
            parcel.readString(),
            parcel.readString(),
            parcel.readString()
        ) {
            id = parcel.readInt()
        }

        override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
            parcel.writeString(Stezenie)
            parcel.writeString(Data)
            parcel.writeString(Zegar)
            parcel.writeString(Posilek)
            parcel.writeString(Samopoczucie)
            parcel.writeString(Stres)
            parcel.writeString(Hiperglikemia)
            parcel.writeInt(id)
        }

        override fun describeContents(): Int {
            return 0
        }

        companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<Pomiar> {
            override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): Pomiar {
                return Pomiar(parcel)
            }

            override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Pomiar?> {
                return arrayOfNulls(size)
            }
        }
    }
```

ANALIZA-ACTIVITY

```
package com.example.mwproto1

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.example.mwproto1.ROOM.Pomiar
import com.example.mwproto1.UI.PomiarAdapter
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_analiza.*
import kotlin.properties.Delegates

public class Analiza : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var textView: TextView
    private lateinit var viewModel: ViewModel
    private lateinit var daoAdapter:PomiarAdapter
    private lateinit var pomiar: LiveData<Float>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_analiza)

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(application)
            .create(ViewModel::class.java)

        textView = findViewById(R.id.TV7)



        pomiar.observe(this,Observer {
            textView.setText(it.toString()) })
    }
}
```

ERROR

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.mwproto1, PID: 11239
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mwproto1/com.example.mwproto1.Analiza}:
>   kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property pomiar
>   has not been initialized
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
>        Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property pomiar has not been initialized
>           at com.example.mwproto1.Analiza.onCreate(Analiza.kt:34)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
>   I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 11239 SIG: 9 Disconnected from the
>   target VM, address: 'localhost:8603', transport: 'socket'

Comment: New error,  old I was available

Comment: Post your viewModelFactory code and rename your viewModel class name to something else like SharedViewModel like that, never name your custom classes like existing classes, that's not good practice

Answer (score 0):

Just like the error said: " lateinit property pomiar has not been initialized"

You probably want to add:
pomiar = viewModel.AverageVM() after you initialize viewModel in ANALIZA-ACTIVITY